# iOS 8.4 MPMediaPickerController bug filtering by podcast

Tags: ios, mpmediapickercontroller, ios8.4

Prior to iOS 8.4, this code was allowing me to select a podcast from my phone:

`MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypePodcast];`

With the latest OS though, the same code now pulls up an empty page. In addition, podcasts were also able to be imported via this code (although the podcasts were buried in the many categories/options):

`MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];`

However even with `MPMediaTypeAnyAudio` specified, no podcasts are able to be shown. I know Apple Music was released in 8.4 so I'm assuming Apple completely redid their `MPMediaPickerController`.

I can't find anything about this in their changelogs though. Is it no longer possible to select a podcast from the phone with `MPMediaPickerController`?

It looks like querying still works via:
`MPMediaQuery *podcastQuery = [MPMediaQuery podcastsQuery];` but that requires a custom UI and more work. I was hoping to use something out-of-the-box like what previously worked in < iOS 8.4

Comment: I'm still bumping into this in iOS 9.3, but I haven't looked at iOS 10 beta 1. Have you tried it there yet?

Comment: Just tested and this is still an issue in iOS 10 beta 1. (Note that you'll also need to add a string for the key `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` to your `Info.plist` file starting in iOS 10). I've submitted this to Apple as radar 27018874.

Comment: My radar was just closed as a duplicate of 19331274 (which has status Open).

Comment: Radar 19331274 is still listed as open, but I haven't re-tested this in the iOS 11 betas.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug introduced in iOS 8.4, and still present in iOS 10 beta 1. Apple is aware of the bug, but it hasn't been resolved yet. I've reported the bug and had my Radar closed as a duplicate (see [Open Radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5059452919087104)).

Answer (score 0):

Still a bug in iOS 10.2. rdar 19331274 is still marked as open.